# How do I determine if my mod_wsgi application is running on HTTPS?

Tags: python, https, apache2, mod-wsgi

I've just inherited a Python application which is running under Apache 2.4, mod_wsgi 3.4 and Python 2.7. The same application serves both HTTP and HTTPS requests.

In the existing code, it is trying to determine if the reqeust was HTTPS by checking the environment:

```
if context.environ.get('HTTPS') not in ['on', '1']:
```

This check is failing, even when the connection actually was HTTPS. On looking at an extended traceback showing the environment variables, I saw that `HTTPS` was not actually in the environment passed from Apache.

So my questions are:

- Is this an Apache configuration problem?
- Is this check completely wrong and should be rewritten to check something else? And if so, what?
- Or should I give up and replace Apache with nginx like I really want to do?

Comment: Are you sure python is [compiled with support for SSL](http://morlockhq.blogspot.com.au/2008/05/python-tip-checking-to-see-if-your.html)?

Comment: @sjdaws `hasattr(socket, "ssl")` returns `True` for me.

Comment: Does Apache proxy pass always to `http://backend` rather than proxy passing SSL connections to `https://backend`

Comment: It's not using proxy at all, it uses `SetHandler wsgi-script`.

Comment: What happens if you change that line to `if context.environ['SERVER_PORT'] != 443:`?

Comment: The canonical way to check this is by looking at the [`wsgi.url_scheme`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables) environment variable. That one is guaranteed to be there by the spec.

Comment: @sjdaws In that case, it still fails, but works if I use `'443'` instead.

Comment: Is that good enough, or do you specifically want to use the original code? Can you print out what `context.environ.get('HTTPS')` is actually sending to maybe give you an idea of what's being sent?

Comment: @sjdaws That key doesn't _exist_ in the environment. Which I mentioned in the original question. :)

Comment: @Cairnarvon `wsgi.url_scheme` is indeed set to `https` in my environment. Feel free to make that an answer.

Comment: Whoa, missed that original statement in the question, answered how to pass `HTTPS` based on original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache's `mod_ssl` can be configured to set the `HTTPS` environment variable, but [doesn't do so by default](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html) for performance reasons.

You could explicitly enable it, but since you're using a WSGI application, it's probably a better idea to check the [`wsgi.url_scheme`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables) environment variable instead; the WSGI spec guarantees its presence, and it won't require any further changes to your application if you do eventually move to nginx.

Comment: Interesting. I already had `SSLOptions +StdEnvVars` set. And all of the variables listed there _except_ `HTTPS` were passed on. In any case, I like portable stuff, so this looks like the way I'll go.

Comment: In recent mod_wsgi versions, it will deliberately remove HTTPS from the WSGI environ dictionary specifically because people were relying on it, meaning they were not writing portable WSGI code. You should use wsgi.url_scheme as indicated by this answer as the standard and guaranteed way that will work for WSGI.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yep, I just read about that in the [mod_wsgi 3.4 changelog](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ChangesInVersion0304).

Answer (score 0):

When using CGI, WSGI or SSI you will need to advise Apache to send the `HTTPS` header otherwise it will beempty. You can do this with [mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html) in the config or .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
   SetEnv HTTPS on
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Strange. I placed this in the SSL virtual host and it _still_ wasn't passed on.

Comment: Today I learned that [beginning with version 3.4,](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ChangesInVersion0304) mod_wsgi strips the HTTPS environment variable and that relying on it in a mod_wsgi app is not recommended.

Comment: Well that makes @Cairnarvon's answer all the better.